# Proguard obfuscating a call to a String resource

Tags: android, proguard

When I obfuscate my code with Proguard, I have a line of code as follows:

`String aString = getResources().getString(R.string.foo);`

Even though I set my proguard configuration file to keep the R class an all its inner classes (and they're been kept), it obfuscates that line making foo a static field of a random renamed **n** class.

How can I make it not to make this specific change and inline the referred string at that point? Or reference the string by the id for that matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Give a try to [-keepclassmembernames](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions)
2. It seems you are doing Android developing, in this case the default `proguard` configuration comes with *Android Studio* works perfect for me. If you are using other IDE, you can just copy that `proguard` configuration to your project.

Comment: I'm sticking with the defaults and working from there. That's the safest way to do it. Thanks